# Displaying data in a tableView from a filtered array

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, swift2, xcode7

I have written code that filters events from Core Data and only prints the events that have a date attribute that is equal to a date that was selected in a Calendar. Heres the code:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "eventPastStringDate = %@", formatter.stringFromDate(selectedDate))

//This prints the exact data that I want
print((eventsPast as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate))
```

This works and it filters that data how I would like and it prints only the events that I want. The problem is that I do not know how to display this data in the tableView. Usually I can display all the data from Core Data in the tableView like this in cellForRowAtIndexPath...

```
let ePast = eventsPast[indexPath.row]
let cellPast = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

// Sets labels in cell to whatever user typed in on the events page
cellPast.titlePrototypeCell!.text = ePast.eventPastTitle!
cellPast.datePrototypeCell!.text = "Date: " + ePast.eventPastDateLabel!

return cellPast
```

...but I am not sure how to access the new data as an array like I did above. Any ideas?

Comment: This is Swift! Use native Swift functions like `filter` rather than bridging to `NSArray` and `NSPredicate`. Just assign the result of the filter operation to the data source array.

Comment: If you have the chance could you maybe give an example? I've looked all over and this is the only way that seems to work with Core Data.

Comment: The best way to get filtered data from Core Data is a predicate assigned to a fetch request. There are thousands of examples here on SO as well as sample code in the Core Data documentation how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have a second array in your class.  When there is no filter, the two arrays are identical.  When there is a filter, then you have a master array with absolutely everything and the filtered array is a small subset.

```
(class var) myFilteredArray = (eventsPast as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
```

Then in your tableview methods:

```
let ePast = myFilteredArray[indexPath.row]
```

And make sure to set the table row size to your filtered array count, not the master array count.  Otherwise you are going to get out of bounds crashes.

Comment: I am getting an Error: Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'eventPastTitle'

Comment: Your filter funtion is returning an array of `AnyObject`.  Cast it to the class you KNOW it is and move on with life.